# Can i Increase the NFC range upto 50cm by making a bigger antenna? i only want to write data into a NFC enabled EEPROM?

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless, eeprom, nfc

As NFC are active upto 15cm range, i/m using a PN532 to write data into a NXP NFC enabled EEprom, which is successful, i want to increase its range by 2X by increasing the Power or size of Antenna for increase in the RF Field, My only Motive is to write a data into the EEPROM not read. will that be possible?
EEPROM has to be powered from the Transmitting End

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes. Practically, you'll have to design a complete NFC frontend to drive a coil that's ca 1m in diameter. NFC isn't really designed with that degree of impedance mismatch in mind, so chances are the tag itself would need to be modified, too. So, not really NFC compliant afterwards.

So, no. The N in NFC is for "near".